# Vertical alignment is wrong for rep in new top bar hamburger menu

Tags: bug, top-bar, firefox, windows-7

The site names and rep are not lined up correctly on the new top bar hamburger drop down:

[image]

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 56.0